# External server codeigniter code php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to use a controller hosted on one server A and use it in other server B

I was thinking to create a controller on host B and use

```
include_once("http://www.server2.com/php/ci/index.php/controller/function");
```

supposing I have a mirror database on host A (B host would use the same database but using data from its server)
Would that work?

What about models?

```
   SERVER A
   application
    | 
    | -----> controller
                |
                | ------> control_a.php

   SERVER B
   application
    | 
    | -----> controller
                |
                | ------> control_b.php(use control_a.php code)
```

Comment: That way won't work (pretty bad security issue if I could include the php code of any remote website), you'll only get the response, i.e. the generated (html, json, text...) file. I suggest you create a REST interface and comunicate between the 2 applications using APIs

Comment: Do you know a tutorial or what API do you suggest?

Comment: You wrote the applications, the API now is your responsability :) Decide how one app will use the other codebase and expose the services accordingly. you could read something about REST with an easy google search, the rest is up to you, since you're the only one who knows how the two applications work

Comment: If the controller on server B would return a value, you could always make a webservice out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using RESTful Services in CodeIgniter.

Refer [RESTful service in Codeigniter](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/)